# How to virtual directory as an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-applications, directory, virtual

How do you configure a virtual directory as an application in IIS to avoid such errors?
I have a web page build using C# visual studio and I added the virtual directory to ISS. Upon running the page, I get the error

```
 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition ='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.


</compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

All this code is currently in my main web.config

Answer (score 2):

In IIS6, you open the properties of the website then click the "Home Directory" tab.

There is a box next to the label "Application Name" - there should be a "Create" button.

Hit the button and it will turn your Virtual Directory into an application.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have been trying to do this but I cannot find the properties option for the website. I am using IIS' default website. So, I created a virtual directory under the default website for my application. how do I go about from here then? thanks

Comment: Right-click on your virtual directory and select properties.

Comment: There is no properties option when I right click. All there is present is Explore, Edit permissions, Convert to Application, Add Application, Add virtual Directory, Manage Folder (browse), Refresh and Switch to content view

Comment: This isn't IIS6 - I'm guessing it is IIS7... All I would say is - there is an option in that list called `Convert To Application` and I would click on it!